# The crash file received after app review from Apple is in JSON format and cannot be analyzed with symbolicatecrash

Tags: flutter, iso, symbolicatecrash

After requesting an app review from Apple, the app was rejected due to a crash. At this time, I received the crash log in JSON format as below.

```
{
"app_name":"Runner",
"timestamp":"2022-11-11 15:18:06.00 -0800",
"app_version":"1.0.8",
"slice_uuid":"168e264b-d858-3918-8bea-74994907868f",
"adam_id":"1574588254",
"build_version":"9",
"platform":2,
"bundleID":"com.raymond.****",
"share_with_app_devs":0,
"is_first_party":0,
"bug_type":"309",
"os_version":"iPhone OS 16.1 (20B82)",
"roots_installed":0,
"name":"Runner",
"incident_id":"10307672-77C6-47A6-AC7C-8D5FF6AF8DAE"
}
......
```

When I tried to analyze this file using symbolicatecrash, the following error occurred.

```
> ./symbolicatecrash 1.crash > symbolicated.crash

No crash report version in 1.crash at ./symbolicatecrash line 1365.
```

What should I do? Thank you in advance.